# Generic datacenter questions

Tags: datacenter

Hope this is the right place to ask a datacenter-related question. I don't have any experience with datacenter administration, and I am aware that the answers to the questions below might change based on many factors.

Generally speaking, in your experience or knowledge,

-how often are hard drives replaced? (once ever two years, three years, etc.)

-how many times are data replicated? (assume the data are critical)

-what is the biggest cost factor of running a datacenter? (power, servers, software licenses, other kinds of hardware, etc.)

Comment: Can not be answered, especially factor 3.

Comment: I don't need absolute answers true for everyone. Anyone has had XP with datacenter administration? I'd like to hear what you got.

Comment: Do you mean managing a datacenter or managing computing equipment in a datacenter? These are two vastly different things.

Comment: if you are referring to the last question, managing a datacenter

Comment: -1 too vague.  too impossible to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Can not be answered. Replace "Data Center" with "Cars" and you realize how. A LOT depends what you do.

For example... I work in a comapny having 2 high avilability data centers. 10 km apart. They purchased all ground between them to lay secure fiber lines for rplication of data. Every computer has 1-2 backup machines on hot standby.

That even includes half a million per quarter rakck sun / oracle exadata systems.

I have my own computers in another data center . one that doees hosting. They dont pay for the systems ;) And make no backups at all. Customers do.

This really is way tooo wide.